# Word to describe the moment when you ask the question, "How did I get here?"

Tags: meaning

Have you ever had that moment when you are in a current situation, usually a good one, but can be a bad situation, too, when you ask yourself the question, "How did I get here?" What is that moment, or phenomena, called?

Comment: Epiphany: a sudden realization.

Comment: @Mitch I usually associate epiphany with a realization in the form of a better understanding about something, not a realization that I know less than I thought I did.

Comment: @Jim There is so little to go on here that epiphany is about as good as it gets.

Comment: I’d say you were ***struck*** *by the thought* that you had no idea  how you got there.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a moment of *[stupefaction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stupefaction)*, the state of being stupefied.

A person is stupefied when they are shocked, amazed, dumbfounded or overwhelmed.  If the shock arises from the circumstances in which one finds oneself, then introspective reflection and a sense of wonder may ensue.

Consider whether the emotion described in the original post might overcome the person in the example Merriam-Webster gives for *stupefaction*:

"Upon hearing the diagnosis of cancer, she just sat there in total stupefaction."